# Rotation Code not working in iOS6 it worked perfectly on iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, ios6

I have this code and it works perfectly on iOS 5 but not on iOS 6 please help

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
    {
        return (orientation != UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) &&
        (orientation != UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `UIViewController`? It has a whole section talking about the changes made for supporting rotations. There are also many existing questions on this exact topic. Please do some searching.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780925/handling-rotation-in-ios6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let try this :
First inside `viewDidLoad` function use this code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
}
```

then, i'm create function that will receive notification for two lines of code :

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)object{
    NSLog(@"orientation change");
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[object object] orientation];
    if(deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        if(deviceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
            NSLog(@"Changed Orientation To Portrait");
            // Handle your view.
        }
    }else{
        if(deviceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
            NSLog(@"Changed Orientation To Landscape left");
            // Handle your view.
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Changed Orientation To Landscape right");
            // Handle your view.
        }

    }
}
```

i hope my answer will help. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS6, "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" method is deprecated.Try setting orientation in plist file.

Comment: I added the needed orienation in plist file, please try the other method here also.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577879/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-is-not-working-in-ios-6