# Resize custom UITableViewCells (SubViews) on Orientation iOS6

Tags: ios6, uitableview, autolayout, autoresizingmask, uideviceorientation

# I have a UITableView with custom UITableViewCells. My views are autorotated on orientation as I have implemented the ios6 orientation methods. 
      
  # I am not using xib file and drawing all the contents programmatically (imageView,label).
   When I rotate my device the tableView and Cells are rotated but cell subviews are not proper in terms of size and position.

# So how to resize the current cells being drawn on the TableView. As the cells are drawn asynchronously and not all at once, how to apply resizing ?

# Do I need to apply AutoResizingMasks or NSLayoutConstraint ?  My TabBar and NavigationBar are properly resized but cells are not.

*****Plz note:** I have not added any block of code, bcoz I simply dnt understand how to proceed as for already drawn cells and those being drawn dynamically after objectForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. As for orientation in ios6, there are many [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780925/handling-rotation-in-ios6/12780927#12780927) for implementing new methods. 

     Initially my views were not supporting rotation till I found that my tabBarController was a RootViewController for the app so I added 
`(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{return YES;
}` 
       in my subclassed TabBarController class

and in my info.plist added key value pairs for supported interface orientations, this values will be global to the application unless you specify exceptions in current UIViewController via 
`- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}`

For implementing rotation in UITableView, I called reloadData(); via using 
`- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}`

Its not necessary to write a custom UITableViewCell Class, as you can redraw cells in 
 `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. 
      As I already had a custom UITableViewCell Class I draw new cells in `layoutSubviews();` by getting `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` method. 
    If you have any custom UIViews inside the cell you need to redraw the rect to support the landscape mode. Basically I am also supporting ios5 so I am not using AutoLayout via XIB. You can also use autoresizing masks to each subviews as per your layout frames.

reloadData(); is not expensive to memory as you don't call for all the cells @ the same time and only the visible cells in the UITableView are redrawn and cells are reused as before.