# OBJECTIVE-C: Rotation Methods doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, landscape

I'm implementing these methods for rotation but they don't work:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

I want to force only one view to landscape and lock the rotation, but the app doesn't catch this methods, and I don't know why. Any solution?

Comment: Is that view which you don't want to rotate is embedded in `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Yes, that matters? @BhavinRamani

Comment: Yes, Please look at this link it helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216594/disable-rotation-for-view-controller-in-navigation-controller

Comment: Thank you dude! This post help me and solved it! :) @BhavinRamani

Answer (score 1):

In youar appdelegate add this method,

```
 - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{

    if ([self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass: [SecondViewController class]])
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; // or UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape for landscape and more you can set
}
    else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

In above code second view controller is your desired view to show in landscape.

Hope this will help :)